# SQL: How to sort query by date (DESC) while having rows with column specified value at top?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, laravel-4

My brain is failing me in this. I'm sure this is easily found by searching, but I'm having a hell of a time wording it to find any relevant results.

I'm using Laravel, so if there's an *Eloquent* solution, that would be preferred, but a RAW query would be fine as well.

I have a table, called **threads**, which has the two columns **status** and of course **updated_at**. I would like to sort by **updated_at DESC**, *but* have any rows with a **status** of a specified value returned on top, but also that group sorted by **updated_at**.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Have you considered just using a union query for this?  Fetch one set of data for the appropriate status and sort it, then union a second query with everything else.

Comment: I'll admit ignorance on unions. I had thought of doing two separate queries, but thought there might be a more optimized and correct way of doing it. I'll look into unions, though. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I believe you need.

```
ORDER BY status=17 DESC, updated_at DESC
```

**Edit**. This `ORDER BY` expression doesn't have any effect on the rows selected, only on their ordering. It works because the expression `status=17`, as a Boolean value, has either the value 1 or 0.  Ordering it `DESC` puts the true ones first and the false ones second. Then the `updated_at DESC` puts the rows in descending order by date.

I'm guessing about `17`.  Put your desired status there  instead.

This

Comment: I did not know you could specify a value like that. Would it still return rows that did not have the value specified?

Comment: Yes, the `column = value` expression, when it appears in the `ORDER BY` clause, has no effect on the rows selected.

Comment: Hey, Ollie, this worked beautifully and turned out to be just as simple as I thought it should have been. Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want

```
select status, updated_at from threads order by status, updated_at desc
```

Comment: that's not right, that would sort by status ascending instead of putting the rows with the desired status at the top

Comment: I have other statuses, and only want rows with a specific status value to be on top, where the other rows with different status values are sorted like normal amongst the rows without any status value.